# Job installed software without telling my team what it was

Tags: software

My first position with this company got migrated due to layoffs. Now working in a different department with new company migration we had a "tech day" no one informed my team what exactly tech day was or what was going to be installed on our personal computers. On another note no one provided us with details on what they call BYOD bring your own device contract in order to migrate and keep a job. Now I asked tons of questions and had a wierd feeling about this software and was told my computer should not be affected by the software. Welp. I have no admin rights to my personal computer interfering with my personal life such as childs school work and my college work. Certain programs are not being allowed to function.  I thought maybe i needed to wipe my computer and start new because honestly its not new. Can not do this. It will not allow. So my supervisor told me to contact IT desk. And ahold to find out its their software controlling my computer. Now i am being told that i am not allowed to take it off my computer. They shut the IT process down. Then i was informed about all this information. Then i was told in order to take it off and keep my job i need another device to transfer this to. Is this legal?

Comment: What country are you in?  Who owns the laptop, you or the company?

Comment: "Now i am being told that i am not allowed to take it off my computer." - If it's a personal computer, you can do anything you want since it's your machine.  If it's a company computer then you should avoid performing school work and other activities on the device, since it's not your personal property, if you agreed to the BYOD policy what has happen likely is legal.  However, you have not provided any specifics,

Comment: When you next go to work, don’t take your personal property with you. Let them supply the computer.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you either agreed to or allowed your company to install their software on your personally-owned computer and for them to take over admin rights to it.

That's YOUR bad choice and there is likely nothing you can do at this point but to re-install the operating system (Windows??) and start over.  If you have personal files on the device, hopefully you can back those up before you proceed.

I would NEVER allow this.  My company provides their laptop for my work and they do what they want with it.  That's perfectly fine, they own it, I connect it to their network, it's "care and feeding" is their problem.  I use it for their benefit.

My personal laptop is for my own use and they have no claims to it but I also NEVER use it for work and I don't connect it to their systems at any time.

This is the proper separation.  Ultimately the choice is yours and your job may be dependent on this arrangement so keep this situation in mind going forward.  It may be time to start looking for a new position.

Comment: My advice would be to buy a new computer for personal use, switch all your personal files to it, delete them off what is now your "work" laptop and never use the "work" laptop for anything personal again.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear who owns your computer; you, or the company. If the company owns it, they can do anything they like. If you own it, they cannot install software without your permission (which can be withdrawn). The moral is, never have personal stuff on a work computer, and vice versa.

If the company wants another machine to transfer this software to, then your supervisor should work on the process of getting you a company computer.

Comment: The op has mentioned several times it’s a boyd job and the computer is theirs.

Comment: It certainly depends on the jurisdiction, but the claim "if the company owns it, they can do anything they like" is not universally true. In Germany, for example, companies cannot install software that is spying on the user or tracking their behavior without following certain very strict guidelines and informing the user. Under certain conditions, employers are not even allowed to read their employees' emails.